# Conda, command to list disk space used for each environment

Tags: conda, diskspace

Is there a conda command associated with:

```
conda env list
```

That allows one to list the size each conda environment is taking up on disk?

Answer (score 2):

Conda doesnt seem to have a command to directly do this. However, for linux, we can use the disk usage tool to list the size of the folders where the environments are stored as follows

```
$ du -sh ~/anaconda3/envs/*
```

The folder where the envs are stored can be seen by running

```
$ conda env list
```